# How to pass data results to a modal by search id

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I created a simple php search
that will search id if has match
it will display the firstname and lastname , My problem
is i want to pass the data to
my modal, My modal inside has a textbox firstname
and lastname.  Is it possible after
i search the id it will display the data on modal using
just php and html? hope
you can help me.

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
include_once('connection.php');
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $sql =  "SELECT id, fname, lname FROM test WHERE id LIKE '$searchq'" ;
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 0){
          $output ='No results!'; 
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
          $fname = $row['fname'];
          $lname = $row['lname'];
          $id = $row['id'];
          $output .= '<div>'.$fname.''.$lname.'</div>';
        }
      }
    }  
?>
```

here is my sample php search form and my modal code:

```
<form  method="post">

        <div class="md-form input-group">
            <input type="search" class="form-control added-padding-2" placeholder="Search..." name="search" id="textsend" 
            maxlength="11" >

            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-pink btn-rounded my-0"  type="submit"  style="border-radius: 50px;" data-dismiss="modal" 
            type="submit" href="#exampleModal3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3" target="_blank"
             role="button" id="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>


   <?php print $output;?>

     </div>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header blue accent-1">

        <h3 class="mt-2" style="color:white;"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> User Information:</h3>
       <a href="index3.php" button type="btn" class="close"  aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

 <form   action="index3.php" method="post"  >

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
       <div class="md-form mt-0">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="firstname" placeholder="First name" id="firstname" value="<?php print $output;?>" required >

      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="col">
        <div class="md-form mt-0">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php print $output;?>" required >
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     <div class="text-center mt-2">
       <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info" style="width:98%; ">Log in <i class="fa fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></button>
    </div>

</form>


     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Advance Thanks .

Comment: "Is it possible after i search the id it will display the data on modal using onclick submit button or jquery"...you don't necessarily need any jQuery, your PHP could create the necessary HTML for the data to be displayed in a modal instantly when the page loads the search result.

Comment: BTW there's no point in using LIKE in your SQL query, since a) you're matching an ID, which isn't something you'd generally search for only part of and b) you're not using wildcards so LIKE will not be able to identify partial matches anyway. You can just replace LIKE with = for this query.